# How to iterate over array and save data using hooks

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

Tha idea is iterate over a array and save (or update) values.

```
const [skills, setSkills] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    Object.entries(array).forEach(([k, v]) => {
       console.log("The skill is: ", k, " and value: ", v)
       setSkills({ ...skills, [k]: v })
    });
}, [array]);
```

The output is:

```
The skill is:  1  and value:  30
The skill is:  2  and value:  40
The skill is:  3  and value:  90
```

That's ok and I assume that "skills" should be:

```
{1: 30, 2: 40, 3: 90}
   1: 30
   2: 40
   3: 90
```

but actually, it only saving the last input. I mean, I see the following:

```
{3: 90}
   3: 90
```

Please, somebody can explain why? And how to do it the right way?
Thanks!!!

Comment: There's no [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) in your question. If the variable with the misleading name `json_h` would actually contain JSON then `Object.entries()` would not return the correct values

Comment: Ok, let me fix the title. It's a simple array. The question is still the same.

Comment: If it's an array then why do you use `Object.entries()`? o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
const [skills, setSkills] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  setSkills([
    ...skills,
    ...Object.entries(json_h).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v})),
  ])
}, [json_h])
```

Comment: That's did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Skills are `array of objects` at first but you change it to `single object` in the loop that's why you only see the last output in the state

this should fix your problem

```
useEffect(() => {
    Object.entries(json_h).forEach(([k, v]) => {
       console.log("The skill is: ", k, " and value: ", v)
       setSkills([ ...skills, {[k]: v} ]) // notice changes here
    });
}, [json_h]);
```

though I suggest save the new values in a temporary array then change the state once this will get rid of unnecessary setState calls

```
useEffect(() => {
    let tempArr = [];
    Object.entries(json_h).forEach(([k, v]) => {
       console.log("The skill is: ", k, " and value: ", v)
       tempArr.push({[k]: v})
    });
    setSkills([...skills, ...tempArr])
}, [json_h]);
```

Comment: Excellent!!! I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: @user3892548 I've edited the question take a look for more information about the question